# как узнать порт сайта в open server?

Tags: php, yii2, openserver

Немного опишу ситуацию.
Я создал на yii2 REST API и хотел через curl посмотреть что получилось.
ввожу такую вот команду

```
$ curl -i -H "Accept:application/json" "http://localhost/users"
```

но он выдает пустую страницу. 
Подскажите как узнать порт сайта в open server

Comment: открыть настройки. там указан пор для всех ваших сайтов. Обычно 80, если не путаю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В настройках OpenServer посмотрите:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]